# Storing and Invoking a delegate of unknown method with multiple unknown parameters?

Tags: c#, delegates, system.reflection

Hopefully I have the right terminology. Looking to make a CSharp Delegate to take in an unknown function with 0 or more unknown arguments.. store all that .. then later Invoke the stored method using the arguments at the time it was stored.

I've checked over many threads and messages and have yet to find a solid answer.  Several places have led to a successful workaround, but usability needs some "syntactic sugar" for 'pretty' code.

Help would be wonderful!!

... The following code works:

> InvokeManager.Eval( 1f, new System.Action(MyDelayedMethod),
>   new object[]{"some argument data", 3412, true} );

... This is the syntactic Goal, can it be done?  How close can we get?:

> InvokeManager.Eval( 1f, Log("some argument data", 3412, true) );

... Working code snippet:

```
    public class InvokeContainer : IComparable<InvokeContainer>
    {
            int _activationStamp;
            Delegate _delayedFun;
            object[] _args;

            public int ActivationTimestamp {
                    get { return _activationStamp; }
            }

            public Delegate Callback {
                    get { return _delayedFun; }
            }

            public object[] Args {
                    get { return _args; }
            }

            public InvokeContainer(float delay, NcTickTimerTool timer, Delegate method, object[] args )
            {
                    _args = args;
                    _delayedFun = method;
                    _activationStamp = (int)(1000f * delay) + timer.GetElapsedTickCount();
            }

            ...

    }

    public class InvokeManager
    {
            private BinaryHeap<InvokeContainer> _heap;
    ...

            public static void Eval( float delay, Delegate method, params object[] args )
            {
                    _instance._heap.Add( new InvokeContainer( delay, _instance._ticker, method, args ) );
            }

            // Gets called externally on a thread

            void Update ()
            {
                    InvokeContainer poppedCallback;
                    int currentTicks = _ticker.GetStartedTickCount();
                    int heapPeekTicks = 0;

                    if( _heap.Count>0 )
                    heapPeekTicks = ((InvokeContainer)_heap.Peek()).ActivationTimestamp;

                    // Invoke all methods which have waited long enough

                    while ( _heap.Count>0 && heapPeekTicks<=currentTicks )
                    {
                            poppedCallback = (InvokeContainer)_heap.Remove();
                            poppedCallback.Callback.DynamicInvoke( poppedCallback.Args );
                            poppedCallback = (InvokeContainer)_heap.Peek();
                            if (poppedCallback!=null)
                                    heapPeekTicks = poppedCallback.ActivationTimestamp;
                            else
                                    break;
                    }
            }

    ...

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than accepting a delegate with an unknown number of parameters, just accept an `Action` (or `Func<T>` if you need to compute a result) and the caller can close over any values they might need to use in their delegate using a lambda.

In addition to being a lot easier on both the caller and your implementation, it ensures static typing and prevents the user from providing a delegate that accepts a different number of parameters, or different types of parameters, from what values they provide with it.